# Something wrong with my GridView code

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, dataadapter

this code never fills the grid view I know that somthing is wrong here the code

```
Imports System.Data
Imports ZidduDataSetTableAdapters
Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Dim filesAdp As New FilesTableAdapter
    Dim filestable As New ZidduDataSet.FilesDataTable
    Protected Sub btnfill_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnfill.Click
        Me.GridView1.DataSource = filesAdp.GetData
        Me.GridView1.DataBind()
    End Sub
End Class
```

and I already created the dataset with wizard called ZidduDataSet.xsd
 and the adapter name is FilesTableAdapter

can any one help?

Comment: This is completely unintelligible. Please rethink, rephrase, reformat, and open a new question (this one will undoubtedly get closed very quickly.) We will donate time and effort to help you, but you have to make a minimum amount of effort as well.

Comment: Please add the actual error message

Answer (score 1):

i am not a VB coder, but i think you should call Databind() function on Page Load event too.

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

the only thing wrong with the code is that **filestable** is never used.  If your gridview isn't showing up then you have a problem else where i think.

1. btnfill_Click  isn't getting called.  Check the .aspx markup to make sure the event handler is referenced.
2. filesAdp.GetData doesn't return any data.
3. GridView1 isn't visible on the page.